# Angular4 What definition of Iterable should I use

Tags: typescript, angular

I have upgraded my app to the latest Angular 4 (beta-8) version. However I keep having the following error :

> `@angular\core\src\change_detection\differs\iterable_differs.d.ts:14: TS2304 Cannot find name 'Iterable'`

I did look up the changelog and found :

> A definition of `Iterable<T>` is now required to correctly compile Angular applications. Support for `Iterable<T>` is not required at runtime but a type definition `Iterable<T>` must be available.

What should I use as Iterable definition here ?

EDIT:

tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    /* for reading your ts source while debugging from a browser */
    "sourceMap": true,
    /* the following two settings are required for angular2 annotations to work*/
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators":true,
    /* noImplicitAny when you want your typescript to be fully typed */
    "noImplicitAny":false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors":true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch":true,
    "noImplicitReturns":true,
    "outDir": "./target/ts"
  }
```

Comment: What is your typescript version? tsc --version

Comment: My ts version is 2.1.4

Comment: Okay, I'm grasping here. you could attempt to add "es2015.iterable.ts" to your 'lib' definition in tsconfig.json, however, this shouldn't really be needed. What libs are in there? "es6" ? or lower?

Comment: My setup is a bit weird as I do rely on sbt and webpack, but I'll add my tsconfig.json for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the [*migration*](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-beta6-2017-02-03) stated in their changelog you should add `es2015.iterable` as a lib inside your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  ...,
  "compilerOptions" : {
     ...,
     "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2015.iterable"]
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried your approach of adding the strings to `lib` but I continued to see the `Cannot find name 'Iterable'` issue. I also tried the suggestion by @Naveed Ahmed (below), but it didnt help
What could i be missing?

Comment: Sounds to me that the compiler is not addressing the right `tsconfig.json`. Or you've not placed the `lib` entry in the `compilerOptions` object?

Comment: I resolved this issue by re-installing typings with 1.x version as I was making use of `ambient` earlier

Comment: Adding libs to the compiler option caused a number of additional errors "cannot find global type xxx".

Comment: @Ernesto then you are missing some libraries, which you probably have to download at `@types`. Check the angular-cli for more info

Comment: I did, also, had an older typescript which made it worse.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the accepted answer for this question but it didn't work in my case.

In my case I added below line in my main.ts

```
///<reference path="./../typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts"/>
```

which fixed the issue, hope this helps someone.