# Changes in package.json for Angular 2 to 4 migration

Tags: angularjs, angular

Currently, the application is on Angular 2.0.0. What are the packages or dependencies that need to be changed for compatibility with Angular 4?
So far i have changed the following,

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "4.0.0",
"@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/upgrade": "4.0.0",
"angular2-toaster": "2.0.0",
"rxjs": "^5.0.1",
"typescript": "^2.1.5",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
}
```

Are there any other packages/dependencies that needs to be changed?

Should I make changes to the tsconfig.json?

```
{


 "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es2015",
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "scripthost"
    ],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "allowNonTsExtensions" : true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/main"
  ],
  "filesGlob": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts",
    "src/custom_typings.d.ts",
    "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "resolveGlobs": true,
    "forkChecker": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally use the files here for guidance: https://github.com/angular/quickstart

It provides the set of basic seed files needed for an application and it is normally kept up to date with Angular since it is part of the Angular docs at angular.io.

Answer (score 1):

There is an online app that guides you in the (easy) process of upgrading 2 to 4: https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: I have gone through this process , and the steps to migrate did not help me. I still errors

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to make changes to ts.config.
The changes you have in package.json seem to be correct.

Couple of points:

- I think "typescript" should be in the "devDependencies" since you won't need that in prod mode.
- I recommend removing "^" from all your dependencies b.c. it's better to lock down the exact version
- I also highly recommend using "shrinkwrap" to avoid loose dependencies within your dependencies.

To install Angular latest version, remove/move your current node_modules folder. Then:

```
npm cache clean
npm install
```

For reference, see the section 'Updating to 4.0.0' 
http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html

Answer (score 0):

You need not make changes in the package.json file manually you can run this command if you are using windows

```
npm cache clean

npm install @angular/common@next @angular/compiler@next @angular/compiler-cli@next @angular/core@next @angular/forms@next @angular/http@next @angular/platform-browser@next @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@next @angular/platform-server@next @angular/router@next @angular/animations@next --save
```

This will help

After you comment

you should update your typescript and also can try changing this in tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es2016", "dom"] //or es6 instead of es2016(es7)
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the windows command to upgrade the packages, but I see errors in `vendor.ts` and `main.browser.ts`

`ERROR in ./src/vendor.ts
Module build failed: Error: Debug Failure. False expression: File  has unknown extension.`
`ERROR in [default] node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/iterable_differs.d.ts:15:47
Cannot find name 'Iterable'.`

Comment: @user3344978 Do you have the Latest Typescript installed as Angular4 uses 2.1.

Comment: I tried with typescript@lastest and also with typescript@2.1.6. But both versions gave me this error `/node_modules/bootstrap-loader/loader.js' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.` ,

Answer (score 0):

My solution in these situations is to use angular-cli to create a new project at the angular version I want (almost always the newest version for me), and then add in the other dependencies I need, allowing the package manager to sort out what version I should have, or asserting my opinion about that through my package manager command options.

This allows me to quickly build a vendor library and quickly test that it will all load without error using the "app works!" project that cli provides.

Once this process is done, you should have a package.json file that you can just cut and paste the dependency sections into your project.

One more thing to look at if you haven't... Yarn. Yarn is a newer package manager from our friends at facebook. It is newer, and therefore less tested than npm, but it has some really nice features and, at least in my setup, runs about 20x faster than npm. Another commmenter mentioned shrinkwrap which is a great tool, so I thought I would just point out another solution in that area.

Comment: Should convert my current project to run using cli to get the right versions? Or should I create a whole new test project?

Comment: I generally just create a new test project, to determine the correct mix of dependency versions.

Comment: Let me try that too. Through manual incremental change, I get the following error at `4.0.0-beta.6` 
`@angular\core\src\change_detection\differs\iterable_differs.d.ts:14: TS2304 Cannot find name 'Iterable'.`

I tried to follow the suggestions provided in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42347142/angular4-what-definition-of-iterable-should-i-use) question on stackoverflow , but neither helped.

Comment: Unless it is not an option for some reason, I would def update to the latest release version of Angular (currently 4.0.1).

Comment: Updating `Typings` to 1.x and adding a reference to `index.d.ts` in `main.ts` did the trick for me